# Render code into MVC view using jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

I have a string  that reaches my controller in the form of a string. It is a List(Model.ToParticipantList) that has the following element template :

```
string.Format("<li id=\"Id_{0}" style=\"font-weight: bold; margin-top: 1px; list-style-type: none; display: inline; margin-bottom: 3px; cursor: pointer; font-size: 11px; color: Black; padding-top: 1px; padding-bottom: 1px; margin-left: 2px; width: 150px;\" 
onclick=\"RemFromList('{0}__#{2}');\">
<a>{1}</a>
</li>,", el.Id, el.Name, "To"));
```

I would like this to pass to my jQuery function and result the following:

```
<li id="Id_1" style="font-weight: bold; margin-top: 1px; list-style-type: none; display: inline; margin-bottom: 3px; cursor: pointer; font-size: 11px; color: Black; padding-top: 1px; padding-bottom: 1px; margin-left: 2px; width: 150px;" onclick="RemFromList('1__#To');">
<a>System System</a>
</li>
```

This works:

```
             document.getElementById('To1').innerHTML=@Html.Raw(Model.ToParticipantList);  //this works 
          // $("#To1").html('@Html.Raw(Model.ToParticipantList)');  //this doesn't 
          // $("#To1").append('@Html.Raw(Model.ToParticipantList)'); //this doesn't
```

What am I doing wrong in the last 2 examples ?

Comment: What does the HTML look like on the rest of the page?  Specifically how is the element defined that has an id of "To1"?

Comment: To1 is a div that contains a li of elements shown in a horizontal li . the RemFromList function removes the element rom the list .

Answer (score 0):

Any of the approaches for inserting the HTML should work. If you take this simple example:

```
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
<div id="div3"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
   document.getElementById( 'div1' ).innerHTML = '@Html.Raw("<li>Using getElementById</li>")';
   $( "#div2" ).html( '@Html.Raw("<li>Using jQuery html</li>")' );
   $( "#div3" ).append( '@Html.Raw("<li>Using jQuery append</li>")' );
</script>
```

It will render this HTML in the DOM:

```
<div id="div1"><li>Using getElementById</li></div>
<div id="div2"><li>Using jQuery html</li></div>
<div id="div3"><li>Using jQuery append</li></div>
```

Essentially they all achieve the same results. There must be something going on in the code that you are not showing in your example. I did notice in your code listing that the when you use **getElementById** the **Html.Raw** is not surrounded by single quotes like you are doing for the jQuery **html** and **append** methods. If you are including the single quotes in the string contained in **ToParticipantList** it will not work.